# Determining shared pointer Type class Incomplete or complete and the reason of crash

Tags: crash, shared-ptr, incomplete-type

A class constructor has the declaration like this...

```
Class A:
{
  public:
 A(int a, SharedPtr<class T>sp = SharedPtr<class T>());
 ~A();
}
```

Now from another class I am destroying this class as shared pointer like

```
delete (SharedPtr<A>*)(*iter);
```

Now as a result it crashes `checked_delete<class T>`

Could anybody say is this `SharedPtr<class T>sp` is incomplete here or what is the cause for crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete (SharedPtr<A>*)(*iter);
```

What is this meant to be?

1) Why are you casting to `SharedPtr<A>`? Are you sure the cast is safe? What type is `iter`? What does `*iter` return?

2) Why **on earth** are you deleting a shared ptr?  Did you create a shared ptr on the heap?! That defeats the entire purpose of shared ptr. You create it on the stack and copy it around as needed, you don't create it on the heap.